# Why can't I increment the variable in my for loop manually?

Tags: python, for-loop

Simple doubt, 
Why is the output for the following codes the same?

```
for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        i+=2
```

Second code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Ouput in both cases:

```
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
```

Why is my counter i+=2 have no effect on my counter i?

Comment: Because `i` is assigned the next value from the iterator at the beginning of each iteration

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: @JoshuaNixon this has nothing to do with generators, there are no generators involved in the example, and even if there were, they wouldn't behave differently.

Comment: `range(x)` is a generator @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @JoshuaNixon no, absolutely it is not. It isn't even an iterator 
 It is a `range` object, which is an iterable sequence. And even if it were, it would be irrelevant to the behavior observed above. But it's definitely not a generator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Oops. You are right, I looked it up :)

Comment: But more importantly, it's not relevant